# debugging SSIS packages - debug.writeline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

The debugging experience in SSIS is not what I am expecting.

I have a script Task that I have added a `Imports System.Diagnostics` at the header of the class, and in the code I have various debug.writeline ("Attemtpting to move file") type messages.

But, they are not displaying in the output window.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Dts.Events.FireInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337081.aspx) instead.

Comment: good call Todd. You can  also use Dts.Log() but viewing this is slightly more cumbersome

Answer (score 4):

[How to: Debug a Package by Setting Breakpoints on a Task or a Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141754.aspx)

[Debugging Control Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140274.aspx)

[Breakpoints in SQL Server 2005 Integration Services SSIS](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1110)

[Watching variables in SSIS during debug - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582166/watching-variables-in-ssis-during-debug)

To capture `Debug.WriteLine` output, download and run the standalone [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for those. Any articles on using debug.writeline ?