# SSIS Execute SQL Task Parameters - Works in dev, but not in prod. How to determine what's different between the systems?

Tags: parameters, ssis, development-environment, environment, production-environment

I have an SSIS package that passes three params to an Execute SQL Task. All three are varchar. When I run on a dev computer, Windows XP, Visual/Mgmt Studio 2005, it works great, params are passed and SQL executes. This however will not run on prod, Server 2008 w/ 2005 SSIS executables.

To debug, I've simplified things down to a simple update command and a few alerts before and after the SQL task so show what values the variables are holding.

What are some reasons that this would work differently between the two environments?

Comment: to watch variables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582166/watching-variables-in-ssis-during-debug and what are variables holding?

Comment: The three variables are all varchars. They hold string values (day, month, year) that are later concatenated and turned into a date. I have confirmed these variable are holding the correct values just prior to the execute sql task.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to different levels of permissions in the two environments; probably you are using two different logins. Can you run your stored proc/Direct SQL into SSMS in the prod environment? If yes, that may elucidate the problem.

Comment: Good thought, but they are being ran under the same user (which has domain admin privileges)